# Can $s_n=1+x+x^2+x^4+x^8+\ldots+x^{2^n}$ be simplified?

Tags: summation

Is there a closed form for a finite sum $s_n=1+x+x^2+x^4+x^8+\ldots+x^{2^n}$?
I apologize if this has been already discussed. Is there some literature on this I can take a look at?

Comment: There is none, otherwise an _infinite_ sum of this kind would also fold nicely, but we know it does not.

Comment: It is more clear if you write $s_n=1+\sum_{k=0}^n x^{2^k}$. I wonder, however, why you've got the extra $1$ term.

Comment: @celtschk You're right. 1 is irrelevant :)

Comment: @Did why do you think it's a duplicate?

Comment: @Elaqqad Because the series in the radical is the same and because at least one of the answers explains what is known about the series itself.

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lacunary_function.